# PHP Captcha Imagettftext Not Working

Tags: php, captcha, imagettftext

Having a hard time implementing a script I came across for a Captcha code. Not too familiar with PHP so any help would be awesome.

**Problem:** Captcha Image does not show up on the live server, but does on my local server.

**Verification File:**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$width  = 90;
$height = 30;
$dir = getcwd().'/fonts/';

$black = imagecolorallocate($my_image, 0, 0, 0);
$angle = rand(0,3);

imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,399,99,$white);


$my_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

imagefill($my_image, 0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

// adds noise
for ($c = 0; $c < 50; $c++){
    $x = rand(0,$width-1);
    $y = rand(0,$height-1);
    imagesetpixel($my_image, $x, $y, 0x000000);
    }

$x = rand(10,12);
$y = rand(10,15);

$rand_string = rand(1000,9999);
//imagestring($my_image, $font, $x, $y, $rand_string, 0x000000);
imagettftext ($my_image, 22, $angle,10, 27, $black, $dir."arial.ttf", $rand_string);
setcookie('tntcon',(md5($rand_string).'a4xn'));

imagejpeg($my_image);
imagedestroy($my_image);
?>
```

**Contact Form:**

```
<img src="verification.php?<?php echo '<span>'.rand(0,9999).'</span>';?>" alt="Anti spam verification" class="verify" />
```

- The font is located in a root folder titled "fonts"

Thank you for your input everyone.

Comment: To locate the problem (i) comment out the line `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` (ii) add the lines `ini_set("display_errors", "On"); error_reporting(E_ALL);` (iii) edit your question and add any error or warnings.

Comment: PS: whats with the span tag inside img's `src` attribute? That's broken html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume your "live" server has `display_errors` off. That means it won't show you the error about what is going wrong. You need to check the PHP error log. My guess is that GD isn't installed.

It should be in `/var/log/apache2` if you are using Apache. If not, you can ask PHP by creating a PHP info file to see what the setup is.

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Comment: This is what I see...                                               GD Support enabled
GD Version bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support enabled
FreeType Linkage with freetype
FreeType Version 2.2.1
GIF Read Support enabled
GIF Create Support enabled
JPG Support enabled
PNG Support enabled
WBMP Support enabled
XBM Support enabled

Comment: @Casey, what about the error log. What does it say? That error log should be the first place you look as it will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Godaddy for this project, and I'm not exactly sure how to check the error logs. Is there another way to catch the errors?

Comment: You have to ssh into your account then and look at it over the commandline. I used to have a dreamhost account so I know you can do this.